# qt model/view set current object

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I have a QComboBox showing data from a QAbstractListModel (sample code below).

```
class Object {};

class ModelObject : public QAbstractListModel {
  //Implementation of model showing vector<Object>
};

vector< Object > objects;
ModelObject model(objects);
QComboBox* combo_box = new QComboBox(parent);
combo_box->setModel(model);
```

I would like to have a way to show a given object in the combo box. Currently, I iterate on each index in the model, and when I find the object I want to show, I call "combo_box->setCurrentIndex". However, it seems a bad design to me.

Any suggestion to do this better ?

Edit: the object I want to show comes from a reference elsewhere (eg: aggregated in an other object).

Comment: [`setCurrentText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop)?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, this is better than mine. However, it relies on the representation of the object in the model, that I will have to duplicate for the setCurrentText call.

Comment: how do you *find the object you want to show*? do you compare `currentData` to some value?

Comment: Question updated: its a reference saved in an other object.

Comment: maybe have a function in your model that looks up the object you want to search for and returns its index, and just call this function when setting the index of your `QComboBox`

Comment: This is what I will do. Thanks.